# Unwanted removal of some stopwords in scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, text-analysis

I want to retain single character in my vector. In scikit-learn `CountVectorizer` even, i keep `stop_word` parameter as `None` internal implementation is removing some characters from the newly created vectors. How can it be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `token_pattern` parameter defaults to `'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'`, which filters all words (provided the parameter `analyzer` is set to `'word'`, which is the default) that only consist of a single character (e.g. 'a' or 'i'). If you set `token_pattern` to a different regex, e.g. `'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b'` single character words should be retained.

Example:

```
In [71]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
In [72]: corpus = ['I like my coffee with a shot of rum.']

In [73]: vec = CountVectorizer()
In [74]: vec.fit(corpus)
In [75]: vec.vocabulary_

Out[75]: {'coffee': 0, 'like': 1, 'my': 2, 'of': 3, 'rum': 4, 'shot': 5, 'with': 6}

In [76]: vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
In [77]: vec.fit(corpus) 
In [78]: vec.vocabulary_
Out[78]: {'a': 0, 'coffee': 1, 'i': 2, 'like': 3, 'my': 4, 'of': 5, 'rum': 6, 'shot': 7, 'with': 8}
```